# How can I use temporary tables, spring Jdbc and connection pool together?

Tags: mysql, spring, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, temp-tables

I have to use temporary tables with spring jdbc and tomcat connection pool to mysql.
I have 4 statement:

- drop temp table if exists (maybe not necessary)
- create temp table
- populate temp  table
- select table joining hard table with temp table

I'm using this code for each one:

```
getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql);
```

I have a problem because the table doesn't exists in the second statement:

> Table 'tmp_table' doesn't exist

I thought that the problem can be the connection pool because temporary table are accessible only by one connection and it is dropped when the connection is closed.

This is my datasource and txManager configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager txManager()
    {
        DataSourceTransactionManager tx= new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        return tx;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to create a new non-pooled connection?

Comment: Setup transactions correctly, if you don't each `execute` will obtain a connection from the pool, with proper tx setup a single one will be used.

Comment: I just put @Transaction annotation in the method...

Comment: Maybe the transaction is automatically closed because the first statement is "DROP" and this is not a transactional action?

Comment: The statement doesn't matter, as long as the transaction is active the same connection is reused. Also *only* adding `@Transactional` isn't enough, you also have to have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your xml.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that transaction is correctly configured (I tested them), moreover I see in spring logs that the transaction is opened and released at the end of the @Transaction method. The problem is that the getJdbcTemplate() uses a different connection for each statement!

Comment: Then you must have configured something wrong as that should tap into the current tx. As a hack you could use a `ConnectionCallback` and do everything yourself, that will give you guaranteed the same connection for everything.

Answer (score 0):

the solution i tried is to use SingleConnectionDataSource.

like this.

```
 SingleConnectionDataSource scds = new SingleConnectionDataSource(jdbc.getDataSource().getConnection(), true);
 JdbcTemplate scdsjdbc = new JdbcTemplate(scds);
 
 scdsjdbc.execute("EXECUTE CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE QUERY!!");

 //file import with postgresql copy command. path is temporary file path.
 CopyManager cm = new CopyManager(scdsTmp.getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(BaseConnection.class));
 cm.copyIn("copy tmp_tenant_product from STDIN with csv", new FileReader(path.toFile()));

 //result will be filled with the temporary table records
 List<Map<String, Object>> result = scdsTmp.queryForList("SELECT * FROM tmp_tenant_product");
```